# Image Manipulation - How do I save original, resize & save in folder A and make thumbnail & save in folder B

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've just started using the Image Manipulation Class, and I can't seem to solve what I considered a simple task. I have a image upload form. The image is uploaded to `./assets/img/uploads/original/` as `imgX.jpg`. Then I store the full path to the image in `$path` and what I am trying to do next is to create a `32x50` thumbnail and store it in `./assets/img/uploads/covers-thumb/` (by default it is saved as `imvx_thumb`) and to resize the `imgX.jpg` into `200x310` and store save it in `./assets/img/uploads/covers-big/` as `imgX_cover`.

Right now I have one problem. With the current code it's like the second resize does't even happen. I only end up with `imgX.jpg` in the `original` folder and `imgX_thumb.jpg` in the `covers-thumb` folder. But I am missing the `200x310` `imgX_cover` in the `covers-big` folder. Please take a look at the code below. I have added `<<` as comment to the parts of the config that are changing. I'm looking forward to your suggestions, thank you.

```
$configI['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$configI['source_image']    = $path;
$configI['create_thumb'] = TRUE; // <<
$configI['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
$configI['width']    = 32; // <<
$configI['height']  = 50; // <<
$configI['new_image'] = './assets/img/uploads/covers-thumb/'; // <<     
$this->load->library('image_lib', $configI);
$this->image_lib->resize();

$this->image_lib->clear();

$configI['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$configI['source_image']    = $path;
$configI['create_thumb'] = TRUE; // <<
$configI['thumb_marker'] = "_cover"; // <<      
$configI['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
$configI['width']    = 200; // <<
$configI['height']  = 310; // <<
$configI['new_image'] = './assets/img/uploads/covers-big/'; // <<       
$this->load->library('image_lib', $configI);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$this->load->library('image_lib'); 
$this->image_lib->initialize($configI);
```

Comment: it works! but, wtf?! :D why didn't I find a single word about it in the documentation at ellislab? Will accept in 2minutes ;) Thank you.